# JSON file in arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json

I'm trying to parse this JSON :

```
 [
  {
  "text" : "Test",
  "color" : "yellow",
  },
  {
  "text" : "Test2",
  "color" : "blue",
  },
]
```

I am trying to get two arrays, one with the key "text" and another with the key "color".

```
NSString *jsonPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"notes"
                                                         ofType:@"json"];
    NSError *e = nil;
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:jsonPath];
    NSArray *parsed = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                        error:&e];
    if (! [parsed isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }

    NSArray *texts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *colors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary* dict in parsed)
    {
        [texts addObject:dict [@"text"]];
        [colors addObject:dict [@"color"]];
    }
```

I have an error with the following code:

```
[texts addObject:dict [@"text"]];
[colors addObject:dict [@"color"]];
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: You should always post the error, not just state that you got one.

Comment: Can you tell us what the error is? Please copy and paste the entire error you're getting. Is it a compiler error or a runtime error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your JSON data, you've got an array that contains 2 dictionaries. Each dictionary has keys for text and color.

You can use a trick on the array to get all the values in one:

First, your code to extract the JSON into an NSArray:

```
NSString *jsonPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"notes"
  ofType:@"json"];
NSError *e = nil;
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:jsonPath];
NSArray *parsed = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
  error:&e];
```

Now the trick:

```
NSArray *textEntries = [parsed valueForKey: @"text"];
NSArray *colorEntries = [parsed valueForKey: @"color"];
```

### EDIT:

The trick is in sending the `valueForKey` message to an array. When you do that, it passes on the message to every object in the array. The array then builds a new array with the answer it gets back from each object it contains and returns the resulting array to you. This does a whole lot of work for you with a very simple statement.

Comment: Why the down vote? If there's something wrong with my answer, please post a comment with where you think my answer fell short.